# Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource, SSL error: Connection reset

Tags: postgresql, ssl, openshift, flyway

Facing connection issue while connecting to postgresql pod running in OpenShift environment. Details are as below
URL: `jdbc:postgresql://XXX:5432/YYY?sslmode=require`

*Flyway 4.2.0 by Boxfuse*

ERROR:

> Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource
>   (jdbc:postgresql://XXX:5432/YYY?sslmode=require)
>   for user 'ABC': SSL error: Connection reset

Just wanted to confirm if I need to add certificates to make the connection work?

Please advise.

Comment: This has nothing to do with certificates. Does the server support StartTLS?

Comment: Yes, we are using flyway service to connect to postgres which are running as services in openshift. The local flyway is able to connect to the postgres. The difference between local and openshift env are fly-way version, posgres driver version

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed this issue by upgrading flyway version to 6.0.7 and postgres driver version to 42.2.8.

The below URL string worked
jdbc:postgresql://XXX:5432/YYY?sslmode=require

Thank you all.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend checking the networking setup of your application which basically means have a look at:

1. The route (does a DNS record exist for your hostname? Is your route pointing to the correct service and service port?)
2. The service (is the target port the port your postgresql is listening on?)
3. The deploymentconfig (did you expose the right port?)
4. The postgresql (it needs to listen on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost/127.0.0.1 -> all interfaces (a common mistake))

Comment: Not one of these conditions would cause a connection reset.